# Fixing Shower Without P-Trap

Tags: plumbing, shower, drain-waste-vent

I have a shower on the first floor that does not have a P-trap.  A previous owner did some remodeling and the shower drain pipe is plumbed right into the top of the waste line with a tee.  You can see the connection just behind the supply lines at the back of this picture:
[image: Picture of shower drain line]
The flow is from the back left of the picture to the front right.  The tee closest to the camera is from the toilet.  The piping runs a few feet further and then joins the soil stack.

What are my options for adding a proper P-trap here?  can I put a pair of 45 degree fittings to jog the shower pipe around the waste line, add the P-trap and then rejoin the waste line from the side instead of the top?  Is there some other approach?

This is all above the ceiling in a finished basement so I know I will have some drywall work to do no matter what.

Comment: Wow I would open it up as close to the shower drain as possible and add your trap, you will need more than 2 45's because you need to create a u or 4 90's

Comment: What is the size of the drain pipe for the toilet. It looks small.

Comment: The drain pipe from the toilet is 3", same as the main line.

Comment: @Ed The 2 45s would be used just to jog the pipe away from top dead center of the main line.  Then I would drop down and install a normal P-trap that enters the side of the main line at a different location.  I would have to cap off the remaining stub on top of the main line.

Comment: Ok I could not see that from the photo , it will make running a snake harder if needed but would work.